# Pattern process name match in Bash

Tags: bash

In bash, I would like to kill a process in case it exists.

I am running this command:

```
netstat -lp | grep 9876
```

Which has output either 1 or 0 lines.

In case it has output 1 line, it looks something like this:

```
tcp 0 0 *:9876 *:* LISTEN 18449/java
```

So I would like the following:

1. In case there is no output, don't do anything.
2. In case there is output, I would like to pattern match `18849`, so the `java` process`.

Then I will kill it.

I don't know how to do 1 and 2 though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bash`'s regular expression matching is sufficient; no need for `grep`:

```
regex='LISTEN ([[:digit:]]+)/java'
if [[ $(netstat -lp) =~ $regex ]]; then
    kill "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the `-r` switch in `GNU xargs` and `GNU grep` with `PCRE` capabilities enabled,

```
netstat -lp | grep -oP '(?<=LISTEN ).*(?=/java)' | xargs -r kill
```

The `-r` flag in `xargs`

```
-r, --no-run-if-empty
       If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the command.  
       Normally, the command is run once even if there is  no  input. This option is a GNU 
       extension.
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `netstat -lp | grep -oP '(?<=LISTEN ).*(?=/java)' | xargs -r kill` ?

Comment: @anishsane: Thanks for the catch! updated now! You can remove it!